# Jest takes 10s to run two trivial TypeScript tests, how do I determine why it's slow?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest to run some TypeScript tests, but it's slow, taking 10s to run the following tests:

```
import "jest"

test("good", () => {
  expect(2).toBe(2)
})

test("bad", () => {
  expect(2).toBe(3)
})
```

I've run it in --watch mode as well and it has the same 10s run when the file changes.

I am using TypeScript in a large project. While there are no modules being imported in the sample file, the tsconfig.json has paths to the whole project.

How do I determine why Jest is going so slowly, so that I can figure out how to speed it up?

---

If I create a .js file with the same tests, and remove the import line, it is fast. This indicates probably something with the TypeScript aspect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'll transpile it to javascript first and then run the tests, so that might be what takes "long".

Answer (score 22):

I got a major speedup by using `isolatedModules: true` in the config.

My configuration now looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('@ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      isolatedModules: true,
    },
  },
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // ...removed...
  },
  moduleDirectories: ["js", ".", "node_modules"],
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This reduced my execution time from 38 minutes (yes) to less than 5 seconds. Thank you so much!

Comment: ts-jest[ts-jest-transformer] (WARN) Define `ts-jest` config under `globals` is deprecated. Please do
transform: {
    <transform_regex>: ['ts-jest', { /* ts-jest config goes here in Jest */ }],
},

Comment: Still very slow. ((

Comment: But the question was... "how do I determine why it's slow?". Not answered here.

Answer (score 6):

Setting `isolatedModules: true` also speeds up tests for me (it seems to disable typescript compiler type-checking).

Since defining `ts-jest` config under `globals` is deprecated, it's better to set it with `transform`:

```
transform: {
  '^.+\\.ts?$': ['ts-jest', { isolatedModules: true }],
},
```

Comment: This was causing `error TS5110: Option 'module' must be set to 'NodeNext' when option 'moduleResolution' is set to 'NodeNext'.` I fixed it by adding `"module": "ESNext",
"moduleResolution": "Node"` to `tsconfig.js`. I don't fully comprehend the consequences of this decision so use at your own risk. More context here: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/4198. In my case, I went down from 5 seconds to 1 ms for a trivial test.

Comment: Okay, so `ESNext` can mess up imports, so as an alternative, consider replacing the default ts-jest runner with [SWC Jest](https://swc.rs/docs/usage/jest). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78052865/576997).

Answer (score 2):

Consider replacing the default `ts-jest` runner with [SWC Jest](https://swc.rs/docs/usage/jest). It seems to be a drop-in replacement, but much faster. In my case, the execution time dropped from 5 seconds to 1 ms for a trivial test.

First install SWC Jest:

```
npm i -D jest @swc/core @swc/jest
```

Then use it in your `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$": "@swc/jest",
  },
};
```

Unlike the `isolatedModules: true` trick, this actually works without messing around with `module` and `moduleResolution` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68724389/jest-takes-10s-to-run-two-trivial-typescript-tests-how-do-i-determine-why-its#comment137600249_75442408)).